# Polygon Intersect Tolerance using Turf

Tags: leaflet, geospatial, polygon, intersect, turfjs

I`m using the intersect function from turf (https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-intersect).
It works nicely in the most cases, but I need to snap a polygon into another.
But, when I have two polygons and I grab a point of one polygon to snap in another, the funtion intersect returns a object, it means they intersects.

Ok, for me, this is a intersection and intersect function return "true":

[image]

But, in this case, intersect functions return "true" too.

[image]
image

Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question.  What does "I grab a point of one polygon to snap in another" mean?  Could you rephrase and try to be more clear?

Comment: Sorry @SethLutske.. I click in one "vertex" of a polygon e atach/snap into another "vertex" of other polygon.
You can simulate this here: https://geoman.io/geojson-editor

Comment: Ok I see what you mean by snapping polygons together in geoman...but its still not clear what is going on in each of the pictures, or what issue you are having.

Comment: The problem is: The function interesect() from turfJs return true when I snap a vertex in other polygon. But I solved it in another way, I used the different() for that. thanks